# What is the best solution in Kentico where only one product/service to sell with fixed price

Tags: paypal, kentico

I am trying to understand Kentico and need one help. I have one product (or service) with fixed price. **This is what I want:** Customer browse home page => click buy button => they will be redirected to form to fill more details (ex:personal detail like name, age, email) => redirect to payment page => Then to PayPal on click of Pay now. Once customer paid, they will be given access to browse different page.

What is best solution for Payment logic here. Do I need to consider any e-commerce feature of Kentico or ignore e-commerce and go with PayPal Buy button is the best? I am also thinking how to keep track of the payment detail if I use PayPay buy button.

PayPal is the only allowed payment type.
Please let me know if you have any inputs.

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you will spend more time and effort attempting to setup that checkout process that you want vs. setting yo the e-commerce solution within Kentico. You can install the Dancing Goat e-commerce site and essentially copy all of the checkout process they have there and get what you're looking for simply by configuring the solution.

Comment: Thanks Brenden and mnield for your inputs here. But I found it difficult to understand the complete flow. I copied/edited Dancing Goat site's checkout process files but still unable to reach the payment. step. I configured the PayPal settings using Sandbox account. Because it doesn't require complete ecommerce features, I hard coded the price and Payment method to Paypal but nothing happens on click of Payment button. Also I noticed there is no code in "\PaymentGateways\PayPalForm.ascx.cs" and on debug code reaches here and do nothing. Is there anything I need to write/configure here?

Comment: and I am using Kentico 10

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [e-commerce membership](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/managing-your-store/products/managing-product-representations/managing-e-commerce-memberships) is what you're after to me; it allows you to restrict access to various pieces of content on your site to paid-up 'members' only.  *e-products* might work, but I think from your description that membership us what you're after.

There are some fairly straightforward steps to setting this up:

- Create the content on your site that will be for 'members'
- Create a [role](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/role-management) that will be used to [control access](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/configuring-permissions/configuring-page-permissions/page-level-permissions-acls) to your content
- [Create a membership group](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/membership-management)
- Create a [new product representing your membership](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/managing-your-store/products/managing-product-representations/managing-e-commerce-memberships)

As Brenden says, you can save a lot of time using the dancing goat checkout if you're new to Kentico.

Also, check out [configuring PayPal in Kentico](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/configuring-your-store/configuring-payment-methods/configuring-paypal).  I've not used it for a while personally, but it is built-in.